# mysql insert event trigger fired at update event

Tags: mysql, triggers

I create a 'after insert' trigger,but it triggered when update the table.
can someone tell me the reason ?

```
mysql version    :5.6.23-log
trigger event    :INSERT
trigger statement: 
             `BEGIN INSERT INTO t_trigger_sync_to_ec(table_name, pk, pk_value, ctime, utime,act) VALUES('t_transact_user_info', 'f_id', NEW.f_id, NOW(), NOW(),'insert');END`
```

bin log:
[Log1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQy6x.png)
[Log2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9e9iI.png)

Comment: Please post your table schema, sample data nd your query, preferably in a codepen or fiddle.  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)